# Print When Expression to print only the last element in the group

Tags: jasper-reports

I have following data set in oracle table and want to generate CSV file from that data.

### My data

```
CaseID  Amount
1000     10
1000     20
1000     50      
2000     30 
2000     10     
3000     30 
3000     20 
3000     20
```

It is necessary to show the following output from above data.

### Required Output

```
CaseID  Amount  Aggregate
1000     10
1000     20
1000     50      80

2000     30 
2000     10      40

3000     30 
3000     20 
3000     20      70
```

Aggregate column is populated by accumulating the sum of Amount according to caseID group.

Group summary should display on last element of the group. But not in the next row, should display in the same row and next column, that matching with the last element.

I tried with 'Print When Expression' for other scenarios, but unable to use with this scenario. Also I have find similar questions, but not cater with this requirement. So would like to know the possible solutions for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something similar with evaluationTime="Auto".  You can have a text element that shows the value on the last record in the group and is empty for other records.  It's not the same as not printing the element at all, but you can't use the print when expression because it doesn't have delayed evaluation.

evaluationTime="Auto" uses the reset types of variables to decide the moment at which it reads the variable values.  Each group has an automatically created count variable that resets with the group, and if you create a new variable that resets on each record you can use it to determine if the current record is the last record in the group.

The whole report would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="jasperreports" whenResourceMissingType="Key" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="816687ff-bb19-4f6b-a2b6-53634ce095fc">
    <style name="dd" isDefault="true" fontSize="10"/>
    <field name="CaseID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="Amount" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="AmountSum" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="CaseIDGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="GroupCurrentCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{CaseIDGroup_COUNT}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="CaseIDGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CaseID}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="af7a5ea9-ffcb-4a7f-aaa8-7d5cab06a579"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CaseID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="a7e2795e-456a-4c6e-946f-8315df453b1f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="afda4fcc-78fc-46f9-8c5c-2e0c4f04dfa5"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{GroupCurrentCount}.equals($V{CaseIDGroup_COUNT}) ? $V{AmountSum} : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I tested with ur jrxml as it is with csv datasource, it is providing better approach to resolve this, only problem is aggregate column doesn't provide the accumilative sum of Amount. Instead it is showing only the last element value in the caseid group. I need to calculate accumilative total.

Comment: There is small mistake in above sample, I have corrected it by adding calculation=`Sum` to AmountSum variable. Anyway thank you for the approach.

Comment: Right, I missed the calculation type of the variable.  I edited my response, thank you for noticing the mistake.

Comment: Thank you, anyway i have vote up and accept the answer based on ur approach.